# gRPC on an exposed network

Tags: grpc

I setup a working server/client with streaming and it works for me without security and dns on a local area network.

Now I feel ready to deploy it on an exposed (public) network and my first I have set the server up with NGINX and a server side certificate from letsEncrypt so that the client is connecting like this.

```golang
creds := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
})  
conn, err := grpc.Dial(host, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))
```

I want to implement authentication at some point, and it seem that gRPC introduces something new called ALTS.

I was wondering if I can implement ALTS in a combination with a username/password authentication on an exposed gRPC service, so that the user gets authenticated one time and then can use the certificate to authenticate after that.

Another idea was to make a (logged in) boolean in the session, where the user would have to call an `rpc` to login before he will get access to the other `rpc`'s

Comment: these are 2 unrelated questions: first about setting up SSL/TLS for a gRPC server, second about ALTS capabilities. the 1st question definitely needs more details: how are gRPC servers and Nginx deployed, what was nginx configuration, what were the errors the you got, etc

Comment: Sorry I am very new to grpc, and I have difficulties where to start. - I managed to set up SSL, but what I really want is a way to only allow logged in users to access the rpc's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TLS (best is mutual TLS or mTLS) helps ensure that the client and server can authenticate each other but TLS only valids the client and server processes, it does not authenticate users of e.g. the client. TLS is a prereq for user authentication (and possibly authorization).

The gRPC docs are lacking but see [Authentication](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/)

A common pattern with gRPC authentication is that the client acquires some form of credential (often an identity token or JWT) from an out-of-band authentication service (e.g. Google|Microsoft|facebook OAuth) that it then passes to a gRPC service as part of the request metadata.

The gRPC service receives the request, pulls the credentials from the metadata and ensures that these authenticate (by using the credentials to determine the issuer and confirming these with the issuer).

Often, the gRPC service then authorizes the user by calling an authorization service to determine which the authenticate permissions (e.g. gRPC methods) the user is permitted to make.

Unlike authentication (OAuth), authorization is often a proprietary implementation. Both authentication and authorization mechanisms are often implemented as gRPC interceptors. Interceptors run before a gRPC service's methods are called and are a good way to block access to unauthenticated|unauthorized users. See [gRPC middleware](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware) for a decent overview of interceptors with examples. Although the repo is for the Go SDK, the principles are true across gRPC language implementations.